# Display the Full Image Size (100% Width/Height) inside a HTML5 Canvas of a certain Width/Height using JavaScript, maybe CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

How do you make an image appear within an HTML5 Canvas of a certain height and width but have the image appear at 100% size? In other words, keep the image's aspect ratio size intact.

Tree image = 'http://kornyezet.sze.hu/images/oktatok/tree3.jpg'

I want this image of the above tree to be at 100% size within something you can scroll.

E.g. like the "overflow: scroll" option shown in blue.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow

The image must be use be sourced in Javascript.

Javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas'); 
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
var imageObj = new Image(); 
ctx.canvas.width = 100; ctx.canvas.height = 100; 
imageObj.onload = function() { 
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0,100,100); 
}; 
imageObj.src = 'http://kornyezet.sze.hu/images/oktatok/tree3.jpg';
```

Html

```
<canvas id="my_canvas"></canvas>
```

Here's a JSFIDDLE but the image is of Google. As you can see it is clearly resized/crunched. Instead I want the full size image to be seen there and some sort of scroll option.

http://jsfiddle.net/jzF5R/

Thanks!

Comment: [`ctx.drawImage(source, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, destinationX, destinationY, destinationWidth, destinationHeight)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) with these parameters, you can resize and crop your image as you wish. If you really want a scrollbar : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36233727/3702797 To keep aspect ratio : http://stackoverflow.com/a/34429774/3702797. Good luck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938346/canvas-width-and-height-in-html5?rq=1

Comment: Do you mean like CSS background "cover"? Check if this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961839/simulation-background-size-cover-in-canvas/21961894#21961894

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imageObj = new Image();
  ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0,window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
  };
  imageObj.src = 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png';
```

```html
<canvas id="my_canvas" style="border:2px solid;"></canvas>
```

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imageObj = new Image();
  ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  alert(window.innerWidth+"X"+window.innerHeight);
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0,window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
  };
  imageObj.src = 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png';
```

this may help.. :)

Answer (score 9):

by getting the width and height of the `img`, after the image loaded and then set the `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` to it you can set the right size of the canvas

after this you need to draw the image on the canvas on the right perspective, this done be setting the `imageObj` then set the left top corner to `0,0` and the right bottom corner to the `width,height` of the image

you can read more about it int [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imageObj = document.getElementById('img');
  imageObj.onload = function(e) {
  ctx.canvas.width = imageObj.width;
  ctx.canvas.height = imageObj.height;
  
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0,imageObj.width,imageObj.height);
    
  };
  imageObj.src = 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png';
```

```css
canvas{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;

}
```

```html
  <canvas id="my_canvas"></canvas>
  <img style='display:none;'id='img'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because there is a difference between the real width of your canvas and the width of your box.

So, if you do this, that should work :).

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas'); 

// What you have to add:
// You can choose clientWidth, offsetWidth... that depends on what you want.
canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() { 
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0,100,100); 
}; 
imageObj.src = 'http://kornyezet.sze.hu/images/oktatok/tree3.jpg';
```

Answer (score -2):

**ADD CSS**

```
#my_canvas{
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Could you update your answer and include a full working example, for example by editing the provided JSFiddle?