# How to use overflow hidden on 1fr grid element

Tags: html, css, css-grid

So I have [this basic setup](https://jsfiddle.net/qg6vm05p/1/) - a canvas area and an animator in a parent grid.
The parent grid is also inside another grid with one 1fr row.
I can resize the animator by dragging a resizer up and down.

```css
canvas {
  background-color: blue;
}

#grid1 {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

#grid2 {
  background-color: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#canvas-area {
  grid-row: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

#animator {
  grid-row: 2;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid1">
  <div id="grid2">
    <div id="canvas-area">
      <canvas/>    
    </div>
    <div id="animator"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the canvas to be bigger than its parent and hide its overflow, but that seems to also expand the parent element.
I've already tried `overflow: hidden`, but that doesn't work

*As a side question*: I also noticed that there is a space of 4px under the canvas, why is that?

Comment: share your full code here

Comment: here is for the last question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50784328/8620333

Comment: `overflow:hidden;` to `div#canvas-area`

Comment: Already tried, doesn't work
Edit: For some reason it works in this jsfiddle and not in my code -_-

Comment: what you mean by `doesn't work` ? what's actually happening ? [check this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/azfnkbs6/)

Comment: It behaves as if there was no overflow hidden, so it expands the parent div

Comment: Okay I made the jsfiddle reflect my code more and now overflow hidden doesn't work anymore @ZohirSalak

Comment: That's because you removed the fixed height and width you had, a parent height is auto by default meaning it depends on the children, it will exapnd to make room for them unless you define a height then there will be overflow and only then where `overflow:hidden` will take effect

Comment: Is there a way to fix it without setting a definite height?

Comment: If you'd think about, you want to hide the canvas if it goes out of bounds, so you have to define those bounds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want the canvas to be bigger than its parent and hide its overflow, but that seems to also expand the parent element.

Normally you'd add a height to the *grid container* so that the the `1fr` in the `grid-template-rows: 1fr auto` is meaningful; otherwise the *grid item* auto-adjusts to the dimensions of its contents.

---

Add `overflow: hidden` to the *grid item* `#canvas-area` along with a *fixed height* to the container (say 400px as your previous jsFiddle had) - see demo below:

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {
  document.querySelector('canvas').height = 300;
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: blue;
}

#grid {
  background-color: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px; /* added a fixed height */
}

#canvas-area {
  grid-row: 1;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden; /* added */
}

#animator {
  grid-row: 2;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="canvas-area">
    <canvas/>    
  </div>
  <div id="animator"></div>
</div>
<button>Change Canvas Height</button>
```

Note that adding `min-height: 0` also does not *grow* the container:

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {
  document.querySelector('canvas').height = 300;
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: blue;
}

#grid {
  background-color: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
   width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

#canvas-area {
  grid-row: 1;
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 0; /* added */
}

#animator {
  grid-row: 2;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="canvas-area">
    <canvas/>    
  </div>
  <div id="animator"></div>
</div>
<button>Change Canvas Height</button>
```

---

#### Why so?

By default grid items have `min-width: auto` and `min-height: auto` (just like flex items). You can see some examples of of this behaviour below:

- [css-grid creates an imaginary column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55007253/css-grid-creates-an-imaginary-column/55007797#55007797)
- [How to make images stay within the rows of a css grid container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46303488/how-to-make-images-stay-within-the-rows-of-a-css-grid-container/46305403#46305403)

and from the specs:

> To provide a more reasonable default minimum size for grid items, this
>   specification defines that the auto value of min-width/min-height also
>   applies an automatic minimum size in the specified axis to grid items
>   whose overflow is visible and which span at least one track whose min
>   track sizing function is auto.
>
> [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#min-size-auto)

---

#### Space below canvas element?

> I also noticed that there is a space of 4px under the canvas, why is that?

That is the *whitespace*, a characteristic of inline elements - you can remove that by making it a block element (add `display: block`) or adjusting `vertical-align` property (add `vertical-align: top`):

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {
  document.querySelector('canvas').height = 300;
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: blue;
  display: block; /* added */
}

#grid {
  background-color: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
   width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

#canvas-area {
  grid-row: 1;
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 0; /* added */
  overflow: auto; /* added */
}

#animator {
  grid-row: 2;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="canvas-area">
    <canvas/>    
  </div>
  <div id="animator"></div>
</div>
<button>Change Canvas Height</button>
```

Comment: Okay I made the jsfiddle reflect my code more and now overflow hidden doesn't work anymore. @kukkuz

Comment: @IBronchart the first row is 1fr and you do not have *defined* height for your *grid container* so it is expected to grow

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. Is there a way to fix it without setting a defined height?