# css-grid and `fr` unit does not work with `overflow-wrap: break-word`

Tags: css, overflow, css-grid, word-wrap

I have a `grid` container with a fixed width and a single row and column containing a single word. When I use the `fr` unit to size the column, `overflow-wrap: break-word` does not wrap the word causing the word in the column to overflow.

To the best of my understanding and [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap),  `overflow-wrap: break-word` is supposed to break at any point to prevent overflow if there is no acceptable break point.

Two things seem to fix this. One is to have a `px` unit for column size. Second is having `overflow: hidden` on the text container. I observed the same behaviour on Chrome(v73) and Firefox(v66).

Does anybody know the reason behind this behaviour ?

https://jsfiddle.net/vdx90qeg/2/

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">
    someverylongword
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  /*using 'px' instead of 'fr' works */
  grid-template-areas: "item1";
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: "item1";
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  /* works when uncommented */
}
```

Comment: adding `min-width: 0` or `overflow` property other than *visible* solves this (the default `min-width` or `min-height` for a *grid item* is *auto*)... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55773596

Comment: yes that does also fix it, as does setting `minmax(0, 1fr)` to the column. But I still don't understand why `overflow-wrap` doesnt get taken into account.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like this problem is very similar to what https://css-tricks.com/preventing-a-grid-blowout/ solves

Set column to `minmax(0, 1fr)` instead of just `1fr`. This approach gives the column a minimum width which was default to `auto`. The goal is to turn the column from indefinitely sized container to a definitely sized container.

codepen link: https://codepen.io/thissushiguy/pen/mYdxjb