# How to align html table to a customize canvas drawing

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, web-frontend

I need to build an UI (HTML 5) with two main components: customized chart drawn in HTML 5 canvas; a table.

The gotcha is that the chart must be aligned with the table. If you horizontally scroll the table, the chart content will scroll too.

[image]

One important restriction is that the chart is very customized. I will not be able to use any existing chart component. I will have to code it myself plotting it on canvas.

I am struggling to figure out how to do it. How to trigger a repaint on the canvas during the scroll? How to know the corresponding coordinates on the canvas of the beginning of each table cell? How do I write the HTML/CSS of both components to ensure that the layout will not break on different screen sizes?

I am still planning the project and I am pretty open to use any framework/language.

I need some light here.

Can you help?

Thanks!

Comment: if you use jquery try this https://github.com/flot/flot for the scrolling part it's easy just use `overflow-x: scroll` for the canvas container.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36219632/html5-canvas-scrolling-vertically-and-horizontally

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but you guys missed the point. The idea is not to scroll the canvas. The problem is how to paint the canvas synchronized with a scrolled html table. The user will scroll the table below and the canvas must be repaint accordingly.

Comment: Check the Q/A I linked to, one of the approach there is to repaint the canvas as if it were scrolled, even though it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the scroll position with jQuery scrollLeft() and set your canvas repaint function to jquery scroll() so that it's updated whenever the scroll position changes.

```
table = $('#container')

updatePosition = () => {
  // Synchronize canvas here:
  repaintCanvas(table.scrollLeft());
}

table.scroll(updatePosition);
```

Here is a demo JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4eg39bfm/5/

Comment: Looks OK! Thank you very much! We will let you know if it does work in the full application. Tks!